# need an example of a get and set

Tags: c#

Can you give an example of how to use the get and set? I need to call the get method in my code but inorder to do that it needs to be set first by evaluating it everytime.

Ex:

```
private static string _formatStr = Product == "test" ? "something": "other";
public static string GetFormatStr

{

get { return _formatStr; }

}
```

So I need this to be set before I call the get method everytime. Call set first and then call get.

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in the code so that we can make a better guess as to your problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you mean that you want this :

```
public static string FormatStr
{
    get
    {
         return Product == "test" ? "something" : "other";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd drop the "Get" prefix from the property

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string GetFormatStr
{
    get { return Product == "test" ? "something": "other"; }
}
```

Comment: copy/paste from question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [C# Language Specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx) or something.